# Separate day/night selector for button text color

Tags: android, android-xml, android-button, android-theme, android-styles

I created a custom selector for button text color:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />
</selector>
```

However, I would like to use `?android:attr/textColorPrimary` for the color in night theme and `?android:attr/colorPrimary` in day theme. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you should use style(theme) instead of selector, you can create textcolor style and set to xml button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create folder `drawable-night` at put night-variant in it (same file name), leave untouched file in common `drawable` folder. this way you can also "overwrite" attributes like `colors`, `dimens`, even `layout`

best option would be to introduce `DayNight` theme support, check out [official doc](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/darktheme), plenty of tutorials in search engines... (look for `DayNight` theming)

Answer (score 1):

Each attribute will have its complementary light and dark color in a day/night mode setting. You can create a new item in the `theme.xml` for light mode and dark mode and use that.

Inside `res` directory create a `values-night` folder and inside that create a `themes.xml` this will contain your night theme. The `themes.xml` in `values` folder contains your day theme.

For example Say: this is your `theme.xml` in `values` folder

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Base.Theme.MyApp">

    <item name="buttonColor">@color/light_base_1</item>

</resources>
```

This is your `theme.xml` in `values-night` folder

```
    <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Base.Theme.MyApp">

    <item name="buttonColor">@color/dark_base_1</item>

</resources>
```

create an attribute in `attrs.xml` file

```
    <attr name="buttonColor" format="color" />
```

Then you can use this new attribute in the selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true" />
<item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/buttonColor" />
```